# Fact table in dimensional modeling has primary key duplicates

Tags: database, dimensional-modeling

I have a fact table at the grain of sales order. The  issue is that people want to see the invoice number but each sales order can have multiple invoice numbers. Which causes my table to have duplicates.

What I did is to create a new table with sales order and invoice numbers with a one to many relationship.

Is this the right approach? I sense having a dimension with more rows than your fact table is an indication of a problem.

Comment: Hi - what is the complete reporting requirement that people have? Obviously asking to include the invoice number in a sales order report makes no sense if a sales order relates to multiple invoices, so that can’t be what they are asking for. Are they asking, for example, for an invoice report?

Comment: They just want to see the invoice number, only around 10% of sales orders have multiple invoices

Comment: Ok - but their requirement still doesn’t make sense (because an order can have multiple invoices) so you need to work with them to come up with a set of requirements that does make sense in all circumstances